# Convertir un array en json desde swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

Necesito convertir un array de strings que obtengo de un xml, en un archivo json para luego poderlo guardar en una base de datos sqlite.

Tengo este código:

```
do {
   let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionaryOrArray, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
} catch let error as NSError{
    print(error.description)
}
```

Pero me da este error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write'
```

El array le creo en el parser xml:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "title" {
        let title: String = foundCharacters.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        self.currentlyConstructingArticle.titulo = title
    }
    else if elementName == "img" {
        let imgString:String = foundCharacters.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        self.currentlyConstructingArticle.imagen = imgString
    }
    else if elementName == "description" {
        let descripcion: String = foundCharacters.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        self.currentlyConstructingArticle.descripcion = descripcion
    }
    else if elementName == "item" {
        self.articles.append(self.currentlyConstructingArticle)
    }

    self.foundCharacters = ""
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrás [edit] la pregunta y agregar el código donde se declara/popula el array?

Comment: Haz un `print()` del array y ponlo en la pregunta

Comment: Ya esta puesto la creacion del array @Mariano

Answer (score 2):

**Para swift 3:**

Dado un arreglo x de strings

```
let stringArray = [ "string1", "string2" ]
```

Creas el JSON a partir del arreglo

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: stringArray, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

Si quieres comprobar vuelves a convertir el JSON a string

```
let string = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
```

Si tienes algún problema es con el arreglo de strings que estás probando

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [ "one", "two" ]
let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(array, options: nil, error: nil)
let string = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: Sería mejor que explicaras tu respuesta para que el que se ha encontrado con un problema sepa cómo arreglarlo. Si sólo se lo arreglan pero no conoce el origen y porqué probablemente vuelva a tropezar en el mismo error.